# Can't add Haettenschweiler font to iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I want to add the Haettenschweiler font to my iOS app and I can't seem to get it installed.

- I added the font to my project and can see it.
- I added the file name as a string under `Fonts provided by application` in my plist
- Used the below to log all installed fonts on `viewDidLoad`

  ```
  for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
      for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
           NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
      }
  }
  ```

(weird, I can't get the above to format as code in SO)

The Haettenschweiler font doesn't show up as being installed and I can't set any objects to this font.

I have installed a different font (Digital-7Mono) the same way and it works as expected. Any ideas?

I did try deleting and re-adding the font- no go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if the font file is added to Copy Bundle Resources phase. Target -> Build Phases tab -> Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: yep, its there. I dont get it

Comment: Also, it's best to do a clean build as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my Mac today and reopened my project and now the font is installed. Not sure what the deal was but it's working.